# Alt+F4 not showing 'Shut Down' in HP G62

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown

I have a HP G62 notebook which runs on Windows 7 Home Premiun 64 bit. I commonly use Alt+F4 to shut down most of the Windows systems I use. But Alt+F4 is not showing a window to shut down my HP. Why is it so ?

Normally Alt+F4 closes anything that is opened in Windows. To test this, I just opened My Computer and pressed Alt+F4. Then the preview pane is working instead of closing the My computer window. How can I bring shut down when Alt+F4 is pressed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many newer laptops have reprogrammed the Function keys up top to be something different than F1-F12.  You have to disable this in the bios/firmware setup.

You can try using the Fn+Alt+F4, and that should sort you out.

Comment: Fn+Alt+F4 worked.